# EF OrderBy method doesn't work with joins

Tags: entity-framework

Following works (ordered by name):
    `from t in context.Table1.OrderBy( "it.Name" ) select t`

This doesn't work (no ordering):
    `from t in context.Table1.OrderBy( "it.Name" )

    join t2 in context.Table2 on t.SomeId equals t2.SomeId select t`

Nor does this (trying to reference the parent table to order):
    `from t in context.Table1

    join t2 in context.Table2.OrderBy( "it.Table1.Name" ) on t.SomeId equals t2.SomeId select t`

Nor does this (trying to order on the child table):
    `from t in context.Table1

    join t2 in context.Table2.OrderBy( "it.ChildName" ) on t.SomeId equals t2.SomeId select t`

How do I cause OrderBy not to be ignored while joining?

Comment: Your not using .Include method? Your relations are not mapped?

Comment: Well, that's the answer (use the include method): context.Table1.OrderBy("it.Name").Include("Table2")

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
(from t in context.Table1
 join t2 in context.Table2 on t.SomeId equals t2.SomeId 
 select t).OrderBy( "it.Name" );
```

However, you should not be using `join` at all, as @moi_meme comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might try ordering after the join, instead of before/during.

```
from t in context.Table1
join t2 in context.Table2 
on t.SomeId equals t2.SomeId 
orderby t.Name
select t
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second example, try:

```
var res = from t in context.Table1
          join t2 in context.Table2 on t.SomeId equals t2.SomeId 
          orderby t.Name
          select t;
```

This should order the joined results.

Comment: I must use the OrderBy method - column name will be dynamic